# MultiaxisArrangement starting not from Zero

Tags: plotting

I want to check different signals (see code as instance).

How can I change both y-axis to not start from Zero, e.g. to start from 8 and 100?

[image]

```
d1 = Array[# + 2 RandomReal[] &, 50, {9, 11}];
d2 = Array[# + 15 RandomReal[] &, 50, {135, 150}];
ListPlot[{d1, d2}, MultiaxisArrangement -> All]
```

Comment: Use e.g.: PlotRange -> {8, All}]  or  PlotRange -> {{8, 13}, {8, 160}}

Comment: Must be very special Zero if capitalized :)

Comment: The PlotRange option does somehow change the scale. I cannot really control the scale, especially not the secondary axis.